# app-server should be considered as an actor in u.c basic flow/ u.c diagram?

Tags: use-case, use-case-diagram

I am building an android chat application which sync with Firebase, and also app server which comunicate with the Firebase for analysing text messages with the help of AI algorithms.
Sholud i considered the application server and Firebase as an actors in use case scenarios and u.c diagram?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, for the same reason that Thomas Kilian has pointed out in his answer to this question:
[Use Case diagram - System as an Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008287/use-case-diagram-system-as-an-actor)